# How to store configuration settings in a asp.net mvc application?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but here it goes.

We are looking to developing an online ASP.NET MVC application. One module of this app is storing the application settings like date format, time format, currency format, ... All kinds of settings that almost never will be changed.

Do we store all these settings in a database Settings table or do we create some of configurationmanager class to store these kind of settings or is there another solution for this?